# How to manage databases with limited amounts of data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

Hi I am building a social network in dreamweaver using php and sql as my server languages to interact with my databases. I am going to use godaddy.com to host my website and they say that they will give me unlimited mysql databases, but they can only be 1gb each. I would like to have one database designated for just user information like name and email that would be contained in one huge table. Then in database 2, I would like to give each user their own table that contains all of their comments. Every comment I would just add a row of data. Pretty soon I would run out of space on database 2 and have to create a database 3 full of comments. I would continue this process of creating a new database everytime I ran out of data on the old one. The problem is that people on database 2 are still making comments and are still creating more data for me to store. I don't want to put a limit on how many comments people can store. I want them to be able to create as many comments as they want without deleting the old comments. Any suggestions on what to do or where to go from here. How can I solve this problem? Also, is there a way to find out how much storage a database has left through code.

Comment: Find a new hoster.

Comment: its ridiculous to write your code base on the arbitrary restrictions of a host, there are several million hosts, and if your doing anything seriously you should look at one of the vpn options.

Comment: @Dagon surely you meant VPS options.

Comment: Change your hosting provider. Otherwise you are setting yourself up for failure. To develop a social network site with a 1GB database size limitation would be preposterous.

Comment: doh yup VPN, just to many TLA (three-letter acronyms) to keep track of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following sql statement to determine the database size in MB.

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", SUM( data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 
"Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES 
where table_schema='apdb'
GROUP BY table_schema ;

+----------------+----------------------+
| Data Base Name | Data Base Size in MB |
+----------------+----------------------+
| apdb           |          15.02329159 |
+----------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the above example, `apdb` is the name of the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think that 1Gb of data should be more than enough to start with for your social network. And if your network grows really really really big you can always move your application elsewhere.

Let's make the calculation:
say: 10.000 users to start with (this seems low compared to Facebook, but it will take you a long time to get 10.000 users to sign up).

```
10.000 x 500(?) bytes of information = 5Mb of data
```

each user makes 100 comments. The average size of a comment is 100 bytes. This also presumes an active community.

```
10.000 x 100 x 100 = 100Mb of data
```

You're still well within your 1Gb database limit.

As soon as you hit the 1Gb: change hosting provider, or start paying...